# Set git server home directory

Tags: git, absolute-path, working-directory

We're tuning up a private git server using an [online manual](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) and now the `git remote add` command looks like:

```
git remote add local git@192.168.0.25:/var/lib/git/our-project.git
```

instead of

```
git remote add local git@192.168.0.25:our-project.git
```

How to set up a working directory for git server?

Comment: Adjust the settings on your `git-daemon` - probably `--base-path` is the one you are looking for, but there are several others... `git help daemon` for more info...

Comment: @twalberg: I'm not using `git-daemon`, but git works (with absolute path). How could this be? I installed the `git-core` package.

Comment: Ah... misread your urls... You are using `ssh` and the username is `git`. In that case, your second invocation would be looking for the `our-project.git` repository in the home directory of the user `git` on the remote system, so setting `git`s home directory to `/var/lib/git` would work (as would simply relocating the repository to `/home/git` or whatever the current home directory is - you'll have to decide which is better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I didn't install a git server for real. The server machine is used by local Git as a dumb file storage with SSH. All the clever stuff is inside of a local Git client! To use everything normally I should install some git daemon.

Git client is a clever flexible thing - it can work with Git server and if not - yeah, it just sends files through SSH.